# Compare time complex of O(logn) with O ((logn)^2)

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o

Is time complex `O(logn)` the same as `O((logn)^2)`? 
Could you prove it?

Comment: No. Yes. Read about definition for big-O...

Comment: (logn)^2 / logn = logn tends to infinite when n tends to infinite

Comment: `lim(F(n) / G(n)) = lim(log(n) / (log(n) * log(n))) = 0` so `O(log(n)) < O(log(n)**2)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of Big-O, we can prove that O(logn) is not the same as O((logn)^2).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How we compare `O(F(n))` and `O(G(n))`? We compute *limit*

```
  lim (F(n) / G(n))
    n -> +Inf
```

then we have `3` cases, if `lim` is

1. `0`: then `O(F(n)) < O(G(n))`
2. Some *positive finite value*: then `O(F(n)) = O(G(n))`
3. *Infinity*: then `O(F(n)) > O(G(n))`

In our case for `F(n) = log(n)` and `G(n) = log(n)**2` we have

```
  lim (F(n) / G(n)) = lim (log(n) / log(n)**2) = lim (1 / log(n)) = 0
    n -> +Inf           n -> +Inf                  n -> +Inf
```

So we have *1st case* and thus `O(log(n)) < O(log(n)**2)`

Comment: In my understanding, the definition of the asymptotic notation O(n) is more general. However, if a limit exists, which is not mandatory but which is the case here, we can conclude. I agree that in almost all cases, this is the method to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table comparing logn and (logn)^2 for some n. Note how (logn)^2 grows quicker.

As an (artificial) example, suppose you have a test for primality for some type of large numbers. If you have a logn algorithm you can handle much larger n's than with a (logn)^2 algorithm. E.g. when you're working with encryption such large numbers are used a lot.

```
                   n    logn  (logn)^2
                  10:  2.303,    5.30
                 100:  4.605,   21.21
                1000:  6.908,   47.72
               10000:  9.210,   84.83
              100000: 11.513,  132.55
             1000000: 13.816,  190.87
            10000000: 16.118,  259.79
           100000000: 18.421,  339.32
          1000000000: 20.723,  429.45
         10000000000: 23.026,  530.19
        100000000000: 25.328,  641.53
       1000000000000: 27.631,  763.47
      10000000000000: 29.934,  896.02
     100000000000000: 32.236, 1039.17
    1000000000000000: 34.539, 1192.93
   10000000000000000: 36.841, 1357.29
  100000000000000000: 39.144, 1532.25
 1000000000000000000: 41.447, 1717.81
10000000000000000000: 43.749, 1913.99
```